# connecting with phpseclib gives sftp error 111

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib to connect to a sftp server using the NET/sftp.php NET_SFTP class included in the library as such:

```
/* sftp connection */
    $this->log[] =  '<b>Connecting to:</b> <i>'.$this->ftpServer.'</i><br/>';
    // Set up a connection
    $sftp = new Net_SFTP($this->ftpServer, $this->ftpPort);
    if (!$sftp->login($this->ftpUsername, $this->ftpPassword)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
    }
    echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
    $sftp->put('filename.ext', 'hello, world!');
    print_r($sftp->nlist());
```

I have chceked that the ftpServer and ftpPort variables are correct and my output is:

> Notice: Cannot connect to nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me:2223. Error 111.
> Connection refused in
> /home/itpabse/public_html/administrator/components/com_itpartner_backup/assets/php/sftp/Net/SSH2.php
> on line 1049
>
> Login Failed

The problem is I cant find documentation for error 111 anywhere. I have tried connecting to the server with filezilla using sftp ssh no problem. Any thoughts on what may be going wrong here?

Logfile from filezilla connecting to the server from the same machine running the script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5BDN-5z0pdmeWM2T093S3dIS2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So what is the value of `ftpServer` and `ftpPort`? Can you connect to the same hostname/port using any standalone SFTP client from the *same machine* that runs your PHP code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ftpServer = nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me port = 2223 and yes I tried to do this with filezilla

Comment: On the **same** machine? Show us a verbose FileZilla log file.

Comment: Status: Ansluter till nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me:2223...
Status: Connected to nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me
Status: Hämtar kataloglistning...
Status: Listing directory /
Status: Kataloglistningen av "/" lyckades

Comment: Verbose log file, please; not a message log from FileZilla GUI. That's useless. And in English! And you still didn't answer me, if you run FileZilla on the **same machine** as the PHP code.

Comment: Your error is coming from `fsockopen`. So the PHP interpreter, itself, can't connect. SuPHP can, depending on the settings, prevent `fsockopen` from making outbound connections, but I think, most likely, Martin Prikryl is on the right track.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have updated my question with a link tot he log file and stated more clearly that I did run it from the same machine as is running the script.

Comment: @neubert If this is the case what do I need to enable?

Comment: Then I assume that `fsockopen("nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me", 2223)` in PHP also fails, right? - While If you do `telnet nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me 2223` on the server command-line, it connects and prints `SSH-2.0...`, right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl 
fsockopen: Cant really tell if it fails, dont know what its supposed to return
    $var = fsockopen("nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me", 2223);
    print('<pre>');
    print_r($var);
    print('</pre>');
prints: Resource id #2 
Telnet shows: SH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8p1-hpn14v6

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Running the example Example #1 fsockopen() Example from php.net prints "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8p1-hpn14v6 "

Comment: It should return `false` is it fails. It's strange, as phpseclib does the same. So what about this: `fsockopen($this->ftpServer, $this->ftpPort)`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I ran `if(fsockopen($this->ftpServer,$this->ftpPort)) { echo 'Connected'; } else { echo 'connection failed';}`

Prints connected.

Comment: And if you do it after trying `new Net_SFTP($this->ftpServer, $this->ftpPort);` first?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Same result...

Comment: And if you replace `$this->fsock = @fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->curTimeout == 0 ? 100000 : $this->curTimeout);` with `fsockopen("nasl2-itpartner.ddns.me", 2223)` in `Net\SSH2.php`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Only difference is now it dosent print the error

Comment: And then what? Says "login failed"? What does `getLog()` return?

Comment: So it works with `fsockopen($this->ftpServer,$this->ftpPort)` but not with `fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->curTimeout == 0 ? 100000 : $this->curTimeout)`. Could you try adding each parameter one by one and seeing which parameter makes it fail? eg. try `fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno)` then try ``fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr)` etc

Comment: Sorry for the late responce, the source of the error has been located as a firewall issue, the port 2223 was only open for the ftp client which was why it was able to connect. It's still very strange that fsockopen on its own was able to connect while phpseclibs implementation was not.. Either way thank  you very much for your help, I learnt a lot both about phpseclib and fsockopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My firewall for outgoing communication as not open for PHP. It was for the ftp client which was why a connection was able to be made that way.

Comment: How did you open your firewall for outgoing for PHP?

Comment: This will depend on which port you are attempting to connect to with sftp in php and also what operating system the server is running. See the manual for your firewall on how to open ports, its no different for this application than anything else.